# ListObjectsV2 - Get only folders in an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am using [AWS S3 JS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html). I have folders within folders in my S3 bucket and I would like to list only folders at a certain level.

This is the structure:

```
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3a/file1
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3a/file2
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3a/file3
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3a/...

bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3b/file1
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3b/file2
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3b/file3
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3b/...

bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3c/file1
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3c/file2
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3c/file3
bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3c/...
```

As you can see, at the level of folder 3, I have multiple folders and each of those folders contain multiple items. I don't care about the items. I just want to list the folder names at level 3. Is there a good way to do this?

The only way I found is to use [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/listobjectsv2command.html). But this gives me also the files which inflates the results set and I would need to do a manual filtering afterwards. Is there a way to get just the folder names at the API level?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This article answers all my questions. https://realguess.net/2014/05/24/amazon-s3-delimiter-and-prefix/

The solution can be done using the combination of prefix and delimiter. In my examples the parameters should contain the following:

```
const params = {
      Bucket: 'bucket',
      Prefix: 'folder1/folder2/',
      Delimiter: '/',
    };
```

Be sure to not forget the slash at the end of the Prefix parameter.

The list of folders will be in the `CommonPrefixes` attribute of the response object.

To give you a real life example:

```
...
const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Prefix: prefix + '/',
      MaxKeys: 25,
      Delimiter: '/',
    };
const command = new ListObjectsV2Command(params);
const results = await s3client.send(command);
const foldersList = results.CommonPrefixes;
...
```

Comment: *Notice* The list of folders in in the CommonPrefixes, and NOT the S3Objects property

Answer (score 0):

using the following method, there was no way to return a non-recursive result. It always returns the entire folder structure

```
command = new ListObjectsV2Command({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Prefix: 'folder1/folder2/'
  })
await s3Client.send(command);
```

so i had to do it manually:

```
let list = await availableObjects(this.root)
list = list.slice(1).map( file => this._categoriesOnly(file.Key)) //folders at a certain level
return new Set(list) // remove dupicates
```