# ListObjectsV2Command - List and get CSV files on S3 sub folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am using AWS S3, Node.js 18x. I have csv files under my S3 subfolders and I want to get those files with a specific date range when it was created for example (jan. 1 - 7 2023). I need those files to create my weekly report so instead of manually downloading the file and use excel to consolidate those files an want to automate it. I have already created a pre-code for consolidating the files my issue right now is how to get those files on my S3 bucket.

```
// const csv = require("csvtojson");
import {S3Client ,ListObjectsV2Command } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
const s3Client = new S3Client({});


export const handler = async(event) => {
    // TODO implement
    
    const params = {
        Bucket : 'bucketName',
        Prefix : 'Reports/customerJourney',
        Delimiter: '/',
    }
    
    try{
        const data = await S3Client.send(new ListObjectsV2Command(params));
        console.log("Success", data.CommonPrefixes);
        return data.CommonPrefixes;
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
};
```

I am taking the code step by step a the moment as of now the code was to show the folders under my S3 bucket but I am receiving response of null. [Reference I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990433/listobjectsv2-get-only-folders-in-an-s3-bucket/67020840#67020840) . I am not quite sure what went wrong on this, also suggestion's that I can explore are also very much appriciated.

Comment: What does the code do?  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @AnonCoward As of now my code is for listing the folders and files from S3 bucket, but as of now it is not showing my specific folder which is 'Reports/customerJourney/'.