# AWS S3 APi - get directories but not files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Imagine a situation where a particular bucket has a very large number of sub directories and files .

The  (java) API - listObjectsV2Paginator returns a collection of contents (files) as well as a collection of common prefixes (subdirectories)

In the interest of efficiency, would it be possible to return either of these , but not both .

My question is similar to [ListObjectsV2 - Get only folders in an S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990433/listobjectsv2-get-only-folders-in-an-s3-bucket)  except that I want to know if is possible to avoid retrieving either sub directories or files.

Comment: Nope.  The [underlying API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) has no such options.

Comment: If you can tolerate a slightly out of date list then consider S3 Inventory which can be generated daily.